# Installing Dojo into Aptana

Tags: dojo, installation, aptana

How would I install support for dojo into Aptana?
Basically I want to have auto completion working for dojo. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process has changed. Instead, you drop a library API file into your project:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries

Comment: This link is now out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You do drop a library API file in your project as described in the link Ingo Muschenetz provided. However, no plugin that I have found currently FULLY supports Dojo content assist or auto completion. As in dojo.byId or dijit.byId are not supported through Aptana.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated link to install Dojo support for Aptana:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/JavaScript_Library_Support

Just follow the instructions under Dojo.

Comment: I don't understand how this work. I've tried to drop files into the project folder, but nothing changes.